# Ubuntu 16.04 screen completely freezes only mouse moves

Tags: crash, driver, nvidia, ubuntu-16.04

Ever since I have upgraded my laptop ([Click here for hardware specs.](http://www.filedropper.com/hardinforeport)) my screen usually freezes. Mostly in chrome or Firefox browser. I am pretty sure this is a Nvidia driver problem but I can't seem to find the solution. I am running a Nvidia Quadro K2100M.

I am currently running Nvidia 361.42. I have tried using open source Xorg server without any luck.

The only solution I have found so far is forcefully turning off the computer by holding down the power button.

Things that I have tried:

1. I got keyboard input
2. I cannot switch to another terminal to restart `lightdm`

Answer (score 12):

This problem came to me occasionally, making me really annoyed.

As illustrated in many blogs, this may be caused by graphic driver problem. For me, my desktop has a NVIDIA video card, you can run `lspci | grep VGA` to see what type of your video type, in my case, it returned:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 2] (rev a1)
```

I followed the instruction on [jiakai zhang's blog](http://jiakaizhang.com/fix-frozen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04/) to reinstall proper drivers for the desktop, hope this will help you.

The key steps in [[1](http://jiakaizhang.com/fix-frozen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04/)] are to reinstall the ubuntu desktop and nvidia drivier by:

```
$ sudo su 
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
$ apt-get install unity
$ apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
$ reboot
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: Providing the instructions, along with the referenced link, would benefit future visitors in case the link ever goes dead.

Comment: Worked for me when all else failed. Thanks. I had installed .run driver but login screen was corrupted. Reinstalling ubuntu-desktop is what fixed this!

Answer (score 3):

Updating the grub settings worked for me! Do the following:

**1. Open the GRUB configuration**

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

**2. Change the value of** `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` **from** `"quiet splash"` **to**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

**and save the file.**

**3. Update & Reboot**

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

More info:

This is a bug in the processor, known as [the c-state bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051). It causes total freezes when the CPU tries to enter an unsupported sleep state. It's a problem for many Bay Trail devices especially with newer (4.*) kernels. There is a simple workaround until it gets properly fixed upstream. You just need to pass a kernel boot parameter and the random freezing stops completely. The parameter may increase battery consumption slightly, but it will give you a usable system. You do this by editing the configuration file for GRUB as described above.

*GRUB* - *boot loader package from the GNU Project, which provides a user the choice to boot one of multiple operating systems
installed on a computer or select a specific kernel configuration available on a particular operating system's partitions;*

*Intel Bay Trail* - *new Atom Processors from Intel. Atom is Intel's family of x86 and x86-64 processors that are optimized
for small computing devices, such as smartphones and mobile Internet devices;*

*C-States* - *used to optimize optimize or reduce power consumption in idle mode (i. e. when no code is executed) - (C0 to C8)*

Reference: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail).

Comment: This solution worked for me like magic. I had Nvidia GForce 1600 graphics. It was crashing almost every day before applying this.

Answer (score 2):

I have since fixed this problem by re-installing Ubuntu 16.04 and not switching from the nouveau video driver. I also disable updates and everything been working good for about 2 months now.

Gaming is pretty good but I usually play steam games so doesn't push any kinda hard core graphics

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem: My PC was freezing randomly. I tried Ubuntu 16, 17 and 18.04 and everything was the same. I tried several drivers and didn't get a solution. I tried several solutions that I found in the forums (including this) and got bad and harmful results.

My solution was: I stopped using the graphical nvidia card, removed it and now I'm using the integrated Intel HD graphics card (Intel® HD Graphics 530 card (Skylake GT2)) and all the problems were solved!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine using a few commands from @Qoros solution above. i just ran `apt-get update`, `apt-get install nvidia-current`, and `sudo reboot`. cheers to @Qoros btw!

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the approaches described in rest of the answers worked.

I was opening multiple terminal tabs running some heavy processes and ubuntu used to freeze when I had 6-7 tabs. I tried monitoring the resources used while I was starting my processes in terminal tabs. You can do it by opening `System Monitor` app and going to `Resources` tab.

What I noticed is that when my RAM(`8GB`) and my swap space(`1GB`) were completely used up, ubuntu would freeze.

As a solution, I increased my swap space and made it `16GB`. After this memory never gets used completely and ubuntu doesn't freeze.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space decsibes how to increase swap space.

Comment: It is always recommended to keep a minimum of Total-Ram/2 as your swap space; for workloads that you think would take up close to your ram capacity. Be careful if you are using SSDs as well; they will burnout if you use your swap space too often.